# Update Text Field only when Variable updates from the cloud in IOS app

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I am using Firebase to append a String of data for an Array. I would then like to display this data on the screen. The view on the screen is a List and each Post is looking at a different part of the Array (example; postName[0] vs. postName[1].

My problem is that as soon as the screen loads, the data has not completely loaded from the cloud yet and therefore the Array is empty. This causes the app to crash saying that "Index out of range" since there is nothing in an array that a Text box is trying to read from.

The Array receives data from Firebase and if the data arrives fast enough no issue occurs, however, sometimes the data does not come fast enough and crashes saying index not in range.

Is there anything I can set up to not load the Text field until the data has finished loading?

Code provided:

```
List(fetchPostModel.postsNearby, id: \.self) { post in
        
    ZStack {
            
            if !fetchPostModel.postName.isEmpty { Text(fetchPostModel.postName[Int(post) ?? 0])
                    .font(.title)
                    .bold()
                    .padding()
            } else { Text("Loading...").font(.title).bold().padding() }
            
    }
    .onAppear {
        fetchFromCloud(postNumber: fetchFromCloud.postNumber[Int(post) ?? 0])
    }

    }
```

Comment: This is very likely an asynchronous issue - however, the question is tagged Firebase but there is no code relating to Firebase in the question. Can you update your tag as to which Firebase product you're using (Firestore or the Realtime Database) and also include that code? Please review the following guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the "Index out of range" you can unwrap the property first to avoid the `Int(post) ?? 0`

```
 if !fetchPostModel.postName.isEmpty { 
     
     if let postIndex = post {
           Text(fetchPostModel.postName[Int(postIndex)])
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .padding()
     }
     
        } else { Text("Loading...").font(.title).bold().padding() }
```

Comment: While this would prevent the code from crashing, it won't address the question about waiting for data to be available before trying to present it in the UI. Firebase is asynchronous and data retrieved from Firebase is only available within the closure following the Firebase call.

Comment: You are correct, but the "waiting" for the data is being done automatically.  The UI wont update until some elements are pushed into the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can create one extension for that

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    public subscript(safe index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
        return (startIndex <= index && index < endIndex) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Now it can be applied universally across different collections

**Example:**

[1, 2, 3][safe: 4] // Array - prints 'nil'

(0..<3)[safe: 4] // Range - prints 'nil'

In your problem, you can use like that

```
List(fetchPostModel.postsNearby, id: \.self) { post in
    ZStack {
        if let currentPostName = fetchPostModel.postName[safe: post] {
            Text(currentPostName)
                    .font(.title)
                    .bold()
                    .padding()
        } else {
             Text("Loading...").font(.title).bold().padding() 
        }  
    }
    .onAppear {
        fetchFromCloud(postNumber: fetchFromCloud.postNumber[Int(post) ?? 0])
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe this will help because if the data has not returned from the Cloud, then it cannot be displayed. Firebase data is only available within the closure following the Firebase function e.g. you have to wait until then before updating the UI. The OP didn't include their Firebase code so it could be something else as well.